# is it possible to find out how many partitions a table has in Cassandra (metadata)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Say my table has several partitions. Can I find out
1) How many partitions the table has
2) The values of the partition keys (not fields used in the partition key but the values)
3) size of the partitions?

Answer (score 0):

> 2) The values of the partition keys

To get all the partitions

```
SELECT DISTINCT <partition_keys> FROM TABLE;
```

But this is a **costly query**, which may even make your node down as this will scan the entire data of your table which is distributed across different nodes.
So much better way would be splitting the queries and running in parallel.

Get the token ranges for the keyspace using `nodetool ring` or `nodetool describering`

Even better way would be split tokens based on the nodes so that number of rows queried will be relatively small.
Once you get the token ranges, run following query in parallel and write the output to a file.

```
SELECT DISTINCT partition_keys FROM table WHERE> token(partition_keys)>=token1 AND TOKEN(partition_keys)<=token2;
```

Merge all the data queried and that's the unique partitions for your table.

> 1) How many partitions the table has

If you get data from the above method, just the count of that will give you the number of partitions.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. You have mentioned CQL queries. Is there a way to do the same using say Java Driver as well.

Comment: Yes. Java driver supports distinct https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Selection.html#distinct--
But getting tokens via java is little tedious. Its better to take token ranges from nodetool and pass it as a input.